# How do I add a menu to the Navigationbar?

Tags: menu, swiftui

I want to create menu like in Files App. I added buttons but I dont know how can I create menu like this in SwiftUI. Do you have any id?

[image]

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:  Button(action: {  }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                                        .font(.system(size: 21))
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **SwiftUI 2** you can use a `Menu` placed in a `Toolbar`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Test")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Menu(content: {
                            Button("Option 1", action: {})
                            Button("Option 2", action: {})
                            Button("Option 3", action: {})
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                                .font(.system(size: 21))
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```